# CollectionView Footer xamarinf forms Sticking to bottom of the page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a collection view in the latest xamarin forms 4.3 and I wonder if there is a way to make the footer of the collection view to stick to the bottom of the page even when there are few items only in the collection view.

Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CollectionView can present a header and footer that scroll with the items in the list. The Footer specifies the string, binding, or view that will be displayed at the end of the list. It could not stick to the bottom of the page.
[image]

**Solution:**

An easy way is to create a custom control with labels to simulate the collectionview header and footer.

**MyCustomControl:**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label x:Name="Header_label" Text="Hader" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red"></Label>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding models}" ItemsLayout="VerticalList">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="ID_label" Text="{Binding id}"></Label>
                    <Label x:Name="Name_label" Text="{Binding name}"></Label>
                    <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding image}"></Image>
                </StackLayout>

            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
    <Label x:Name="Footer_label" Text="Footer" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Green"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

**Model:**

```
public class model
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Binding the content in custom control, you could binding in MainPage as well.

**Please Note:**
Before you initialize Xamarin.Forms in your MainActivity.cs, add the following flag.

```
 Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
```

[image]

I have upload on GitHub, you could download from Collectionview/MyCustomControl folder for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

**Updated:**

Or you could control the Footer according to the count of the collectionview items.

Use the `IsVisible` property when you crate the custom control.

```
   <Label x:Name="Footer_label" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" Text="Footer" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Green"></Label>
```

Make the custom control inherit `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    private bool _IsVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsVisible;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_IsVisible != value)
            {
                _IsVisible = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisible");
            }
        }
    }
```

Set the `IsVisible` according to the count.

```
 if (models.Count <8)
        {
            IsVisible = false;

        }
        else
        {
            IsVisible = true;
        }
```

This sample has already uploaded on Github in updated folder.
[image]

Comment: Zang thank you for your detailed answer.What you are saying really that out of the box the collection footer will never stick to the bottom of the page when you have 1 item or 2 . I wanted to use the collection footer out of the box but I cant I have to use a stacklayout and do an endexpand.Correct?

Comment: yes, the original footer of collectionview would not stick to the bottom of the page. The easy way is to use a custom control like the sample in my reply.